# ajax jquery - passing data with parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I want to use `request.getParameter()` in my jsp page so I use some these code:

```
var ajax_call = function updateLocation(position){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    async: true,
    url: "test1.jsp",    
    data: "lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&longg="+ position.coords.longitude ,
    success: function(msg){    
        alert("blahblah");
    }
});
}

var interval = 1000 * 1;
setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

I have received success alert but the `test1.jsp` page is not call yet. If I use

```
data: "lat=1&longg=2" //for example
```

Everything runs correctly. Anyone know please!

Comment: you are not passing the value of `position` to the `ajax_call` function

Comment: `alert(position.coords.latitude)` before ajax call to check that you have got value

Comment: I have done use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` before these line of code. But it seems like the test1.jsp is not invoked yet!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the geolocation API to get the location, so what you might be looking for is

```
var interval = 1000 * 1;
setInterval(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajax_call);
}, interval);
```

Comment: I do have passed the location before!

Comment: @louisnt see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h3t3K/2/ (check the network tab of browser) - you can see the `lat` and `longg` are being sent

Comment: I saw it. But still dont know how to fix, may be problem is on the jsp site